# Parsing function arguments without arguments delimiters

Tags: compiler-construction, boost-spirit

I'm working on a project where I need to translate NetLogo to another programming language. I'm using Boost Spirit and I've already implemented some of the project grammars that store simple code syntax into an AST.

The problem I'm facing is that right now I can't tell if an identifier is a variable name or a function name. Also, I don't know if a specific function call needs one, two, or multiple arguments, so I don't know when to stop looking for more arguments.

For example, a function call can look like

```
id1 id2 id3 id4
```

That could be:

- `id3` is a function that has `id4` as argument (let's say the return value of that is `id5`), and `id1` is a function that has `id2` and `id5` as arguments

But it could also be:

- `id1` has `id2` `id3` `id4` as arguments (all but `id1` are variable names)

I've thought about using Symbols and adding new items each time a variable or function is declared, this would help to differentiate variable names and function names, but...

- How can/should I store the number of arguments a function requires using Boost Spirit? Maybe using another Symbol table with Semantic Actions while parsing the function definition?
- Once I know how to get the number of arguments needed, how can I get that value once I find a function identifier while parsing an expression?
- It's a good solution to use Symbols to differentiate variable names from function names?

Comment: Maybe it helps to take a look at how a compiler compiles a sourcecode into machinecode.

Here's a very basic rundown of what a c compiler does:

1st) syntactic analysis. Splits the code in tokens, e.g. "int void();" -> "int", "void", "(", ")", ";"

2nd) check if this syntax is correct. e.g. "int void(;" would be incorrect

3rd) write each declaration of either a function or a variable into a symbol-table with Type-Information

4th) in the semantic analysis (this is where your problem lies) you check if the semantics of your program are correct. e.g. int test = std::string { "test" };

Comment: If I'm not wrong, steps 1 and 2 are handled by the Spirit grammar. Then, the 3rd step is one of the two questions I'm asking for, so I suppose that going for that Symbol table is the best way to go? And the 4th step is the one I don't know how to deal with (at least with the function arguments part).

Comment: Rethinking what you said, I think my problem is not in the 4th step but in the 2nd. I don't know how to parse the function calls, due that I don't have any token delimiting where arguments start and finish

Comment: Why the question is tagged C++ and even Boost.Spirit? There is nothing about either of them.

Comment: Because I'm using Boost Spirit to develop the parser, and I'm looking for some advice about how to deal it in general, but also with those libraries. I will update my question to reflect that better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I've done is the following:

- Created a Symbols table using the function name as the key, and the number of arguments as data stored.

```cpp
qi::symbols<char, int> f_args;
```

- Used a Semantic Action on the function parser to get the function name and arguments list, and send it to an external function to store the data on the Symbols table.

```cpp
void store_function (std::string name, std::list<std::string> args) {
    f_args.add(name, args.size());
    std::cout << name << " " <<  args.size() << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
function_ = (
        lexeme[(string("to-report") | string("to")) >> !(alnum | '_')]  // make sure we have whole words
   >   identifier 
   >   ('[' > argument_list > ']')
   >   body
   >   lexeme[string("end") >> !(alnum | '_')]
) [ phx::bind(&store_function, _2, _3) ];
```

- When a function name is found outside a function definition (meaning that is a function call), I load the data stored on the Symbols Table to use it on a repeat directive and expect the exact number of arguments the function needs.

```cpp
function_call = 
    function_name >> 
    repeat( phx::ref(n_args) )[identifier];

function_name = 
    !lexeme[keywords >> !(alnum | '_')] >> 
    &lexeme[f_args [phx::ref(n_args) = _1] >> !(alnum | '_')] >> 
    raw[lexeme[(alpha | '_') >> *(alnum | '_' | '-')]];
```

The only question this answer does not answer is the last one. Hopefully, someone with more experience in this field will explain it.